# Exception :org.apache.hadoop.hbase.masternotrunningexception

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am running hbase using java,my hbase started earlier with ease ,now when I am giving "list" command in

hbase(main) :001:0:>>list

It types "TABLE" and give so many lines of java on terminal and ended with

ERROR :org.apache.hadoop.hbase.masternotrunningexception: Retried 7 times

I stopped the hbase and restarted, but it didn't work for me.

**This is the trace of logs:**

```
14/02/18 07:16:17 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client
connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000
watcher=hconnection
14/02/18 07:16:17 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection
to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate
using SASL (unknown error)
14/02/18 07:16:17 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier
of this process is 5461@ubuntu
14/02/18 07:16:17 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server
null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting
reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:597)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
14/02/18 07:16:17 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly
transient ZooKeeper exception:
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException:
KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
14/02/18 07:16:17 INFO util.RetryCounter: Sleeping 2000ms before retry #1...
14/02/18 07:16:18 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection
to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate
using SASL (unknown error)
14/02/18 07:16:18 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server
null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting
reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:597)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
14/02/18 07:16:19 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection
to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate
using SASL (unknown error)
14/02/18 07:16:19 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server
null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting
reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:597)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
14/02/18 07:16:19 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly
transient ZooKeeper exception:
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException:
KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
14/02/18 07:16:19 INFO util.RetryCounter: Sleeping 4000ms before retry #2``
```

**my hbase-site.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!-- Apache 2 License ommitted to keep the output short  -->
<configuration>
    <property>
       <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
       <value>file:///home/hduser/HBASE/hbase</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/home/hduser/HBASE/zookeeper</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
      <value>2222</value>
      <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
      The port at which the clients will connect.
      </description>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
      <value>localhost</value>
    </property>
 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your zookeeper is running fine and you don't have any name resolution related issue. Also, make sure that you have added the **hbase.zookeeper.quorum** property in your **hbase-site.xml**. If the problem still persists please show us your hbase-site.xml file.

Comment: what should be the value for this property?I have installed hbase on ubuntu in standalone mode and hadoop for single node cluster.

Comment: This is not working..I kept localhost as value..I have displayed the Hbase-site.xml.....please tell some solution if possible......

Comment: You actually don't need all those properties as you are running HBase in standlaone mode. Only the first 2 properties are sufficient.

Comment: I also tried with only those two properties, but this issue of "list" command is kind of intermittent.sometime it shows me my tables and sometime it give either org.apache.hadoop.hbase.masterNotRunningException or java.lang.reflect.undeclaredThrowableException.Even if i left the client Port property in my Hbase-site.xml file.some time this shows table,sometimes gives exception.